Compilation Error undefined reference to sql::mysql::_get_driver_instance_by_name when Using MySQL Connector C++
I am working on a simple connection to MySQL on a Windows machine using Visual Studio Code. I downloaded MySQL's official Connector/C++ version 9.1.0.
code:
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0

#include "mysql-connector-c++-9.1.0/jdbc/mysql_driver.h"
#include "mysql-connector-c++-9.1.0/jdbc/mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql-connector-c++-9.1.0/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h"
#include "mysql-connector-c++-9.1.0/jdbc/cppconn/resultset.h"
#include "mysql-connector-c++-9.1.0/jdbc/cppconn/statement.h"

using namespace sql;
int main()
{
    const char *host = "localhost";
    const char *user = "root";
    const char *password = "p@ssword123";
    const char *database = "vscodetest";

    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
    driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();

    sql::Connection *con = driver->connect("tcp://localhost:3306", user, password);
    sql::Statement *stmt = con->createStatement();
    sql::ResultSet *res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tbtest");
    while (res->next())
    {
        std::cout << "Column 1: " << res->getInt(1) << ", Column 2: " << res->getString(2) << std::endl;
    }

    delete res;
    delete stmt;
    delete con;
}

I am trying to compile the following command:
g++ ./src/main.cpp -I ./include -L ./lib64/vs14 -lmysqlcppconn -o main

However, I get the following errors during compilation:
main.cpp:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `check(std::string const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `check(std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > > const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `sql::mysql::_get_driver_instance_by_name(char const*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What might be causing this error and how can I fix it? Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

you can't use visual studio libraries with gcc
